# How to verify that an iTunes backup is valid?

Tags: macos, itunes, backup, restore, verify

Is there a way to **verify** that a backup of an iPhone is valid (other than wiping the device and attempting to restore it :))?

I've had a recent **catastrophic** incident involving an iTunes encrypted backup, with the key stored on the keychain, that won't restore complaining of wrong key (Details on [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/192153/7488)), and that's made me remember the old IT adage that:

> Your backup strategy is only as good as your data restoration capabilities...

So, is there a way to verify that a backup that has complete successfully is valid and working (i.e., would restore itself successfully)? I don't have several iPhones to test, and wiping the "source" phone to attempt to restore it - and maybe fail! - doesn't seem like a good idea.

Thank a lot in advance.